# Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (13): ymax

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a graph showing species optima and tolerances across three different models wap, lg and reg, however I keep getting the error `Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (13): ymax` I read it was something to do with the fill but I am sure that I have defined the fills correctly? I also tried just keeping species common to all three models so that there weren't any NAs in the dataframe but I got the same error. Can anyone work out the issue?

```
specoptima<-read.csv("regspecopt.csv",header=TRUE)

ggplot()+
geom_point(data = specoptima, aes(x = Species, y = wapopt), color = "red",pch=21,size=3)+
geom_point(data = specoptima, aes(x = Species, y = lgopt), color = "blue",pch=23,size=3)+
geom_point(data = specoptima, aes(x = Species, y = regopt), color = "green",pch=23,size=3)+
  xlab('Species') +
  ylab('Height m AHD')+theme_classic()+
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=specoptima$Species,ymin=specoptima$wapopt-specoptima$waptol, ymax=specoptima$waopt+specoptima$waptol), width=0)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=specoptima$Species,ymin=specoptima$lgopt-specoptima$lgtol, ymax=specoptima$lgopt+spectopima$lgtol), width=0)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=specoptima$Species,ymin=specoptima$regopt-specoptima$regtol, ymax=specoptima$regopt+specoptima$regtol), width=0)

structure(list(Species = structure(c(13L, 12L, 4L, 9L, 11L, 5L
), .Label = c("A.agglutinans", "A.exiguus", "A.subcatenulatus", 
"H.wilberti", "J.macrescens", "M.fusca", "P.hyperhalina", "P.ipohalina", 
"S.lobata", "T.inflata", "T.irregularis", "T.salsa", "Textularia"
), class = "factor"), wapopt = c(NA, 178.2315, 177.5775, 177.1053, 
169.4055, 167.8907), waptol = c(NA, 15.21344, 6.385151, 8.477989, 
10.844778, 9.444243), lgopt = c(190.3974, 187.1097, 177.6777, 
170.332, 173.4925, 174.8782), lgtol = c(8.236862, 4.204461, 12.198399, 
9.714885, 10.590835, 8.939749), regopt = c(190.3974, 186.8404, 
177.6699, 174.0947, 173.2112, 172.8087), regtol = c(8.609964, 
4.767529, 11.754856, 9.363322, 10.508812, 9.539666)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Perhaps you could include `data = specoptima` inside of initial `ggplot()`, then you won't need to keep repeating `specoptima$...` to extract columns and can consistently reference the same data frame throughout. Also, there's a misspelling in first `geom_errorbar` with "waopt" which should be "wapopt".

Comment: Hi Ben, good idea thank you! I am still fairly new to coding so any hints and tips like that are great! Thanks for spotting the typo too :)

Answer (score 5):

Like Duck says, you had a couple of typos. But here's *why* you had a couple of typos - unnecessary repetition in your code. The more times you have to type the name of you data frame, the more likely you are to have a typo. Long and unwieldy lines of code with minimal spacing between operators also makes in harder to see these.

Your geoms can all inherit their data from the `ggplot` call, and you don't need to do `specoptima$variable` inside your geom or stat calls, so your code simplifies to:

```r
ggplot(data = specoptima, aes(x = Species)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = wapopt), color = "red", pch = 21, size = 3) +
  geom_point(aes(y = lgopt), color = "blue", pch = 23, size = 3) +
  geom_point(aes(y = regopt), color = "green", pch = 23, size = 3) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = wapopt - waptol, ymax = wapopt + waptol), width = 0) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lgopt - lgtol, ymax = lgopt + lgtol), width = 0) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = regopt - regtol, ymax = regopt + regtol), width = 0) +
  xlab('Species') +
  ylab('Height m AHD') +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Or even better, reshape your data to avoid repeated geom calls:

```r
tidyr::pivot_longer(specoptima, cols = -1,
                    names_sep = -3, names_to = c("type", "b")) %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = b) %>%
  mutate(ymin = opt - tol, ymax = opt + tol) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Species, color = type)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = ymin), pch = 23) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = ymax), pch = 23) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax), width = 0, color = "black")
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot that I could just specify the data argument, will be handy for future code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. The issue was that you were calling a variable that was not present in your data (literally you misspelled its name). Here the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
ggplot()+
  geom_point(data = specoptima, aes(x = Species, y = wapopt), color = "red",pch=21,size=3)+
  geom_point(data = specoptima, aes(x = Species, y = lgopt), color = "blue",pch=23,size=3)+
  geom_point(data = specoptima, aes(x = Species, y = regopt), color = "green",pch=23,size=3)+
  xlab('Species') +
  ylab('Height m AHD')+theme_classic()+
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=specoptima$Species,ymin=specoptima$wapopt-specoptima$waptol,
                    ymax=specoptima$wapopt+specoptima$waptol), width=0)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=specoptima$Species,ymin=specoptima$lgopt-specoptima$lgtol,
                    ymax=specoptima$lgopt+specoptima$lgtol), width=0)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(x=specoptima$Species,
                    ymin=specoptima$regopt-specoptima$regtol,
                    ymax=specoptima$regopt+specoptima$regtol), width=0)
```

Output:

[image]